# couldn't connect to host - wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron

Tags: wp-cron, http

I've moved my wordpress website to new dedicated server. Website is running few cron jobs setup by wp-cron. As soon as i moved the website to new server cron jobs stopped running. I've debug bar installed, the HTTP Request bar turns red and showing this error:

> > couldn't connect to host

Complete screenshot is attached.
[image]

Any assistance in resolving this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a support ticket with your host, as it's probably related to their environment. From the error, it sounds to me like they might be blocking `curl` in their environment, probably for security reasons. They may be able to unblock it, or you may need to find an alternative.

Comment: I already checked curl is enabled.